# How to multiply multiple columns with the same ID in excel

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID   ColB    ColC   ColD
102     2       1      2
103     2       3      4
104     3       3      2
104     6       7      5
105    33       3      3
105    22       2      2
106     1       3      2
```

I would like to populate a new column E which finds every time an ID appears and sums ColC and ColD of this row and multiplies the sum by ColB. All these should be summed up for each time the ID value appears, eventually filling a table of unique ID values.

Using 104 for an example it should look like

```
= (B4) *(C4+D4) + (B5) *(C5+D5)
= (3)  *(3+2)   + (6)  *(7+5) = 87
```

I tried a combination of PRODUCT() and SUMIF() however I am not getting the desired result since I am relying on both multiplication and summation of various cells based on the same identifier...

Comment: good catch! thank you @ScottCraner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8=104)*B2:B8,C2:C8+D2:D8)
```

[image]

Comment: I am attempting to generalize your solution to allow for when data is entered in the future using A:A and so on however this does not work...

Comment: Great answer! I never knew what `SUMPRODUCT` did. This assumes that the user knows which IDs are duplicated. To the OP: Do you need to have a way to (semi-)automatically identify the duplicates? i.e. skip 102, 103 & 106?

Comment: You cannot include any cells with text in them. @JohnnyThomas

Comment: @ScottieH this only will return the values where column A = 104, not all duplicates.

Comment: @JohnnyThomas use this: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10000=104)*B2:B10000,C2:C10000+D2:D10000)`

Comment: @JohnnyThomas, just posted an answer to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much automation you are looking for, or how "clean" you want the answer. I'll post a way that you *can* do it. Not necessarily the best or cleanest. You can adjust to suit your own taste.

First, I made a "scratch" column F. I put this formula in F2:
`=B2*(C2+D2) + B3*(C3+D3)`
I copied this formula into all of the rows F2:F8
This gives the desired value for ALL the rows, not just the duplicates. Next, in Column E, I deal with this by only showing the values that have a duplicate line. The formula in E2 is:
`=IF(A3=A2,F2,"")`
You can hide Column F if you wish, or place it in a another column outside of the viewing area.
YMMV

Comment: You can also use _Conditional Formatting_ and _Filters_ to only show the first row of duplicate data, if you'd like. Comment here and I'll edit my answer to show that.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to automate the process of finding the sum of Column E based by ID each time there is new data added to the table, and generate a new table with unique ID and with the corresponding summed value from Column E, you may want to give `#powerquery` a shot.

Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

The steps are:

1. Highlight the range of data, use **From Table** function under the `Data` tab to add the data to **Power Query Editor**;
2. Use **Custom Column** function under the `Add Column` tab to add a custom column with this formula: `[ColB]*([ColC]+[ColD])` You can name the new column as `ColE`;
3. Use **Group By** function under the `Transform` tab to Group the columns as shown below:

[image: Group By]

4. **Close & Load** the result to a new worksheet (by default).

Then you should have something like below:

[image: Output1]

Each time you are making new entries to the source table, just need to right click somewhere within the output table and select **Refresh** (or go to `Data` tab to click on the **Refresh All** button).

[image: Output2]

Here are the codes behind the scene for reference only. All steps are performed by built-in functions without advanced coding. Cheers :)

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"ColB", Int64.Type}, {"ColC", Int64.Type}, {"ColD", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "ColE", each [ColB]*([ColC]+[ColD])),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"ID"}, {{"ColE", each List.Sum([ColE]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```